# How to upgrade to APFS from Mac Mojave?

Tags: macbook-pro, ssd, catalina, apfs

I am trying to upgrade the Samsung EVO SSD I put into my MacBook Pro 2012 to APFS so I can upgrade to Catalina. I’m currently running Mojave.

In Recovery Mode, the standard instructions on the internet are to select the drive, and click on APFS from the Edit menu. But my Edit menu does not have that option visible, I only see things like Undo, Redo, Cut, Copy, etc, and they are dimmed out. Someone else suggested that there may be something about the drive that just needs to be erased and installed as APFS from scratch. But in the Recovery Mode’s Disk Utility’s Erase panel, the formats I can choose are Mac OS Extended, MS-DOS, and ExFAT. There is no APFS option.

What do I need to do to either upgrade it to APFS or erase it and install it from scratch as APFS?

Comment: You format your drive (APFS or HFS+, etc) through Disk Utility found via the Menu Bar.  It's not found in the "Edit Menu"

Comment: Double-check your recovery partition's macOS version. At the boot chimes, hold the Opt [alt] key & wait until the disk selection screen appears. The recovery partition will specifically list the version, as *'Recovery-xx.xx.xx'*. Make sure it's at least 10.13.xx

Comment: For an overview:  https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/355027/macos-mojave-wont-install-updates-past-10-14-1-due-to-requirement-for-apfs-form?rq=1 Now decide which part do you need help in, to avoid making its answer a blog post :) @julkarham

Comment: @Tetsujin Thanks. I don’t see any Recovery Partition, I just see my disk, NewDrive. What does it imply that I don’t see a recovery partition?

Comment: … it makes me wonder how you got into Recovery Mode without one - did you get a spinning globe during the boot process? If you did, I would expect that the Internet recovery you ended up in would be quite capable of APFS.

Comment: The installer for Mojave and Catalina will *convert* your drive "on the fly" from whatever you're using now (JHFS+ most likely) to APFS.  However, you *must* be using an SSD.  To find out if macOS "sees" your drive as an SSD, issue this command:  `diskutil info disk0 | grep -i "Solid State"`.  It will give you a "yes/no" answer.

Comment: Also, are you using a fusion drive setup in that MacBook Pro?  In other words, did you convert your SuperDrive bay to a hard drive and then create a fusion drive using a new SSD and the old disk drive?

Comment: @Tetsujin yeah, i got a spinning globe.

Comment: @Allan it returns Yes, so I assume it sees my drive as an SSD. What should I do next?

Comment: @Allan I honestly don't know about the fusion drive. I can't even remember how I set up the hard drive. I think I used SuperDuper. I followed some online guide for how to upgrade a MacBook Pro's old hard drive to an SSD because it made the computer faster.

Comment: @ankii That might work, I'll see what I can do with it. Thanks

Comment: That’s good.  Now, just to be certain, you have a Time Machine backup, right?  Also, can you post the output of `diskutil list` please?

Comment: /dev/disk0 (internal, physical):
   #:                       TYPE NAME                    SIZE       IDENTIFIER
   0:      GUID_partition_scheme                        *250.1 GB   disk0
   1:                        EFI EFI                     209.7 MB   disk0s1
   2:                  Apple_HFS NewDrive                249.7 GB   disk0s2

Comment: I usually just back up my computer to iCloud so the files won't be lost, and I use iCloud Desktop. I can use Time Machine if necessary

Comment: time machine is better.  Can you post the output to your question?  If you want to get the output into your clipboard for easy pasting, use the command `diskutil list | pbcopy`

Comment: I believe I already posted the output there above, if that is what you mean by “your question”. I had to take some time off this project but am now looking to solve it again. What do you think the next step is? Thank you

Comment: Also, why is time machine better than iCloud Drive?